# Control content of reusable react component from outside

Tags: reactjs

I have a scenario to create reusable table component which accepts the initial data from calling component, but should perform filtering locally, so that these logics can be reusable. By having local state for the rows of the table and altering it during filtering, i'm able to achieve this.

But the problem is, for such tables, i'm unable to alter the content from the parent component, as the state couldn't be changed from outside.

```
var App = function(props)
{
    var [tableRows,setTableRows] = useState(props.dataRows);
    var resetData = ()=>{
        setTableRows($.extend([],props.dataRows));
    };
    return
        <React.Fragment>
            <button onClick={resetData}>Reset Table</button>
            <myFilterableTable rows={tableRows}/>
        </React.Fragment>
}

var myFilterableTable = function(props)
{
var [rows,setRows] = useState(props.rows);

var filterRows = (query)=>{
    setRows(performFilterOn(rows,query));   //assume performFilterOn returs filtered rows
};

return
    <React.Fragment>
        <input placeholder="filter" onChange={filterRows}/>
        <table>
        rows.map((row)=>(
            <tr>
                                            //assume row content <td>s here here
            </tr>
        ))
        </table>
    </React.Fragment>
};
```

In the above example, filtering works as expected, but reset table doesn't work. I want to achieve both.
So, my question is, how can i have a component whose content can be changed locally within the component and at the same time be changed from outside?

Answer (score 1):

In react it's recommended to have one state for same data. In your case you store the same data in two different states (`tableRows` and `rows`).

You should directly use `props.rows` in your `myFilterableTable`:

```
var myFilterableTable = function(props) {
  var filteredRows = (query) =>{
    return performFilterOn(props.rows,query)); 
  };

  return
    <React.Fragment>
        <input placeholder="filter" onChange={filterRows}/>
        <table>
        filteredRows().map((row)=>(
            <tr>
                                            //assume row content <td>s here here
            </tr>
        ))
        </table>
    </React.Fragment>
};
```

General rule: For derived state (in your case filtered rows) always use props directly. **Never** have duplicated state!

---

**UPDATE 1**

As questioned in the comments, the component doesn't rerender anymore. This propblem is occuring because there is no state update when `onChange` of the filter input is called. So react never knows it should rerender.

To resolve this you have to let react know that the filter string has changed:

```js
var myFilterableTable = function(props) {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState(""); // choose your default value here

  var handleFilterChange = (event) => {
    setQuery(event.target.value); // this will trigger the rerender
  }

  var filteredRows = () => {
    return performFilterOn(props.rows, query)); // now you can use the query state directly
  };

  return
    <React.Fragment>
        <input placeholder="filter" onChange={handleFilterChange }/>
        <table>
        filteredRows().map((row)=> (
            <tr>

            </tr>
        ))
        </table>
    </React.Fragment>
};
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

As questioned in the comments, `myFilterableTable` is not resetable from outside. With the existing code this is not possible because the `query` state is [uncontrollable](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) from `App`.

To solve this issue `myFilterableTable` needs two more props possibly named `query` and `onQueryChange`.

The code could look like this (assuming that `query` is a simple input string):

```js
var App = function(props)
{
    var [tableRows,setTableRows] = useState(props.dataRows);
    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

    var resetData = ()=>{
        setQuery("")
    };

    const handeQueryChange = (event) => {
        setQuery(event.target.value);
    }

    return
        <React.Fragment>
            <button onClick={resetData}>Reset Table</button>
            <myFilterableTable query={query} rows={tableRows} onQueryChange={handleQueryChange}/>
        </React.Fragment>
}
```

```js
var myFilterableTable = function(props) {
  var filteredRows = () =>{
    return performFilterOn(props.query)); 
  };

  return
    <React.Fragment>
        <input placeholder="filter" onChange={props.onQueryChange}/>
        <table>
        filteredRows().map((row)=>(
            <tr>
                                            //assume row content <td>s here here
            </tr>
        ))
        </table>
    </React.Fragment>
};
```

Also consider creating a **custom hook** here if you want to **reuse stateful logic**:

```js
const useFilterableTable(values){
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

  const handleQueryChange = (event) => {
    setQuery(event.target.value);
  }

  const reset = () => {
    setQuery("")
  }

  const applyFilterOnValues() => {
    // some filter based on values and query state
  }

  const filteredValues = applyFilterOnValues();

  return { filteredValues, handleQueryChange }
}
```

Code after using this custom hook:

```js
var App = function(props)
{
    const { filteredValues, handleQueryChange } = useFilterableTable(props.dataRows);

    return
        <React.Fragment>
            <button onClick={resetData}>Reset Table</button>
            <myTable filteredRows={filteredRows} onQueryChange={handleQueryChange}/>
        </React.Fragment>
}
```

```js
var myTable = function(props) {
  return
    <React.Fragment>
        <input placeholder="filter" onChange={props.onQueryChange}/>
        <table>
        {props.filteredRows.map((row)=>(
            <tr>
                                            //assume row content <td>s here here
            </tr>
        ))}
        </table>
    </React.Fragment>
};
```

Comment: sorry, i don't get it here. If state is not maintained inside myFilterableTable component, how can i refresh the component during filter? Without having 2 states, how can i achieve this scenario - (filter from inside, reset from outside)?

Comment: @user1661984 i have updated the answer. Please let me know if this was your problem.

Comment: thanks for your effort here, being the only person to respond to this question. I assume filteredRows would be an array, not a function. Anyway, this is similar to the code i have put in the question. With this filtering will work, but reset will fail because query will always have a value after filtered for the first time. So, even if reset it called from outside, only filtered result would be rendered, isn't it?

Comment: No, `filteredRows` is a function, i forgot to put the `()` before `.map(...)` (already updated the answer now). Regarding the reset you are right. It will not work with your current code. I think you have to reset the query state in my answer. I don't know how your `query` exactly looks like. Maybe it would be the best if you provide a minimal [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) example. Then i could check whats exaclty not working out for you.

Comment: thanks again. I don't have a working example, but only trying to figure out the concept here for any resuable component which has a state. You can assume query as a simple string. Even then, i don't see a way to reset the query when we perform reset from outside, isn't it? We can call setQuery only inside this component, right?

Comment: You are right! Only the component that declared the state *should* change it. The problem here is that the `query` state is uncontrolled (from `App` perspective). I update my answer again to show it to you with an example and how you might improve it further by using a custom hook.